# unrecognized selector sent to instance defaultRepresentation ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

Below is my code which was working on previous version but in iOS 8 app gets crashed. Please help.

```
ALAsset *asset = self.mArrassets[indexPath.row];
//    NSURL *savedAssetUrl =asset.defaultRepresentation.url;
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
NSURL *savedAssetUrl =[representation url];
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message. What type of object does it believe `asset` to be?

Comment: Your asset instance does not look to be of type ALAsset. Check to see what it is by using a breakpoint or printing it out:

    NSLog(@"class is %@", [asset class]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably means that `self.mArrassets` has at least one object that is not `ALAsset`. `NSArray` may not determine what kind of an object stores. It must be reference type thats all.

The code below shows how to avoid such problems:

```
NSObject *asset = self.mArrassets[indexPath.row];
if ([asset isKindOfClass:[ALAsset class]]) {
//    NSURL *savedAssetUrl =asset.defaultRepresentation.url;
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    NSURL *savedAssetUrl =[representation url];
}
else {
    NSLog(@" this is not ALAsset! The class is %@", [asset class]);
}
```

Comment: This will avoid the crash but will probably just hide whatever the underlying problem is.

Comment: Not at all. If he will have different classes inside NSArray he will be able to add multiple if-else and print warning if he forgot one of them.

Comment: Unless it's unexpected that he has different classes in the array, which it seems like it is (but of course the OP has provided very little context).